# How To Select Template Based On Language Switch?

Tags: php, joomla2.5, multilingual, banner

I have a Joomla 2.5 multilanguage website and I want to have a different banner on the English version and on the French version. I know that I can duplicate the template and assign them to the specific language but I am doing a lot of modification in the CSS and I don't want to double the changes! 
I did add this condition in my index.php but only the first banner will display on the EN and the FR website.

```
<?php if ($this->language = 'en-gb') : ?>
<div style="background-image: url(/templates/mega_calibra/images/bannierEN.png);"></div>
<?php elseif ($this->language = 'fr-fr') : ?>
<div style="background-image: url(/templates/mega_calibra/images/bannierFR.png);"></div>
<?php endif; ?>`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Better alternative: assign a class to the body (e.g. lang-en-gb etc.) and then handle that in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Basic PHP error

   if ($this->language **==** 'en-gb')
2. I think $this->language will return en-GB and fr-FR (note the uppercase) so check with a var_dump() on $this->language.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vdespa for your help! I feel very dumb, what a stupid mistake! You are my savior! Thanks so much!!!